# React execution order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I think I need help with react's mechanism of registering in which order callbacks should been called. Here is an example:

```
export const ProviderWithChildren = ({children}) => {
  console.log('ProviderWithChildren');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ProviderWithChildren effect');
  }, [])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('ProviderWithChildren layout effect');
  }, [])

  return <div ref={console.log('ProviderWithChildren ref without callback')} onClick={console.log('OnClick not callback')}>
    {children}
  </div>
}

export default function Task() {
  console.log("App");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App Effect");
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("App Layout Effect");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={(e) => console.log(e.innerHTML, 'App ref callback')}>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
    </div>
  );
}
function ChildA() {
  console.log("ChildA");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ChildA effect");
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("ChildA layout effect");
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}

function ChildB() {
  console.log("ChildB");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ChildB effect");
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("ChildB layout effect");
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <>
    <ProviderWithChildren>
      <Task />
    </ProviderWithChildren>
  </>
);
```

Logs order will be:

1. ProviderWithChildren
2. ProviderWithChildren ref without callback
3. OnClick not callback
4. App
5. ChildA
6. ChildB
7. ChildA layout effect
8. ChildB layout effect
9. App ref callback
10. App Layout Effect
11. ProviderWithChildren layout effect
12. ChildA effect
13. ChildB effect
14. App Effect
15. ProviderWithChildren effect

I understand that component is a function so it executes line by line and all logs from body (not hooks) will run as expected:

1. ProviderWithChildren
2. execute ref={} body to attach result to node: ProviderWithChildren ref without callback
3. same to onClick: OnClick not callback
4. App
5. ChildA
6. ChildB

Docs say that useLayoutEffect will run before browser repaints the screen:
after we reached 'return' statement in ChildB our nodes tree is ready to be mounted, so we need to run all useLayoutEffects in correct order. If 'ChildA layout effect' logs before 'ChildB layout effect' - does it mean that after 'return' statement in component is reached - only then react register useLayoutEffect calling in some kind of "queue" but doesn't call it after node tree for single component is fully built? And the same it does with useEffect? 
I will be appreciate for explanations or resources where this logic is described.

Also `<div></div><div></div> App ref callback` is called after useLayoutEffects in child components. So how to explain all of this?